# Disable button click effect in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-imagebutton

I created a simple ImageButton in my app and im using and image in it.

I had like that when I click the button that it wont show that it was clicked (not sure how it is called but when the button changes color).

My button looks as follows:

[image]

and when I click it becomes:

[image]

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/returnButton"
    style="?android:borderlessButtonStyle"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_rarrow"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_Username"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_Username">
</ImageButton>
```

I want to remove this gray background even when clicked because it shows boundaries that I wish to hide.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can apply a transparent background to the `ImageButton`

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by adding one line of code.

```
android:background="@null"
```

Hoping it will be helped

Answer (score 0):

Apply a background to the **`Button`**:

```
android:background="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 0):

Within your code, you can use this:

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```